# openoffice-writer check viewcursor in table

Tags: cursor, openoffice-writer, openoffice-basic

I have a table with the Property: Name = 'Images'.  
I want to write a check if my ViewCursor is present in this table or not.
You can get the location of the ViewCursor with this code:

```
vViewCursor = ThisComponent.getCurrentController().getViewCursor()
```

But I don't know how to check whether the vViewCursor is in the table: 'Images' or not.
Does anyone have an idea how to do that?

I wrote macros in Openoffice Basic. The table is in OpenOffice Writer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `TextTable` property of the cursor.  For example:

```vb
If Not IsEmpty(oVC.TextTable) Then tableName = oVC.TextTable.getName()
```

See also Listing 8.3 of [Andrew Pitonyak's macro document](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php).